# Add a $\pm$ to the label in order to distinguish two different cases

Tags: labels, ref

I have an equation and I would like to label it in order to refer to it later on in the text, say

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
 f^\pm(x)=\ldots 
 \end{equation}
```

This labels the equation with, say, (1) and referring to this equation by

```
In the equation (\ref{eq1}), we have...
```

gives me something like

> In the equation (1), we have...

But since the equation includes two different cases f^+ and f^-, I would like the label name to be (1\pm). How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX, SE.  An equation can have only one label.  If you like to distinguish two cases, than you need to write more equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\tag` and manually step the `equation` counter.

Explanation: `\begin{equation}` steps up the counter; however `\tag` will cause the counter to be stepped down.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We have a double equation
\begin{equation}\label{double}
f^{\pm}(x)=\dots
\tag{\theequation$^{\pm}$}
\stepcounter{equation}
\end{equation}
We also have a normal equation
\begin{equation}\label{single}
g(x)=\dots
\end{equation}
We can reference equation~\eqref{double} and equation~\eqref{single}.

How about~{\let\pm=+\eqref{double}} and {\let\pm=-\eqref{double}}?

\end{document}
```

Note: `twocolumn` is just to make a smaller picture.

[image]

An abstracted version that also works with `hyperref`.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\protected\def\hpm{\ensuremath{^\pm}}
\newcommand{\pmnumber}{\tag{\theequation\hpm}\stepcounter{equation}}
\newcommand{\eqrefp}[1]{{\let\pm=+\eqref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\eqrefm}[1]{{\let\pm=-\eqref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

We have a double equation
\begin{equation}\label{double}\pmnumber
f^{\pm}(x)=\dots
\end{equation}
We also have a normal equation
\begin{equation}\label{single}
g(x)=\dots
\end{equation}
We can reference equation~\eqref{double} and equation~\eqref{single}.

How about~\eqrefp{double} and \eqrefm{double}?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats really nice, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can cheat by redefining `\pm` while referencing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\tagpm{\stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation\(\pm\)}}
\newcommand*\eqrefp[1]{{\def\pm{+}\eqref{#1}}}
\newcommand*\eqrefm[1]{{\def\pm{-}\eqref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqi}\tagpm
  f^\pm(x)=\ldots 
\end{equation}

\eqref{eqi}

\eqrefp{eqi}

\eqrefm{eqi}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


zzz
\begin{equation}\label{zzz}
 1=2
 \end{equation}

pm
\begin{equation}\label{pmcase}% dot use numbers in label
 f^\pm(x)=\ldots 
 \end{equation}

plus
\begin{equation}\label{+case}% dot use numbers in label
 f^+(x)=\ldots \tag{\theequation+}
 \end{equation}

pm
\begin{equation}\label{-case}% dot use numbers in label
 f^-(x)=\ldots  \tag{\theequation+}
 \end{equation}

see \eqref{+case} and \eqref{-case}
\end{document}
```